# Visual Studio Team Services - Attaching an attachment to a workitem

Tags: c#, api, azure-devops, attachment, patch

I'm create a simple desktop application, which add work items to Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online). My concept application is near to completion and the last element was to send an file as an attachment.
The sending work, it just the attaching of the attachment to the work item.  I keep on getting Method not allowed response.

The code is simple, as I've tried to limit anything that could stop it working.

Could someone please point out what Is wrong within this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add attachment requires "Patch" method, try with the code below:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;


HttpResponseMessage response = client.PatchAsync(url, content).Result;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

And you also need to add "[" and "]" in "msg":

```
msg.Append("[");
...
msg.Append("]");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I've tried to look for the PatchAsync, but can't seem to find the required extensions etc, so I can use the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi reference.
It may sound stupid, but where do you get the extension?

Comment: @ChrisCooper From nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client/

Comment: Hi thanks for this, but now I'm getting bad request.  I only have the option of client.PatchAsJsonAsync not client.PatchAsync.

Comment: @ChrisCooper I can get client.PatchAsync. Are you using the nuget package in the link?

Comment: Sorry, I had created an override method, which that was.  I removed the override and uninstalled and reinstalled the nuget package and it work.
Thanks